# How to proceed on hung Windows update patch installation?

Tags: windows, windows-update, patch, hung

My ASUS laptop running Windows 8.1 (x64) is hung on installing a Microsoft patch. I ran Windows Update yesterday, and Windows Update spent about 20 hours attempting to install patch 12 of 29. In my patch set, 12 of 29 is a Visual Studio patch.

After about 20 hours, I rebooted the machine. When I rebooted the machine, I selected ***Update and Restart***. Now, the machine is hung on the same patch during shutdown. I'm on the dark blue screen that says *Keep your PC on until this is done.*

Its pretty apparent the Visual Studio patch is not going to install. I attempted to press and hold the power button to force a shutdown, but its not working (the machine refuses to shutdown and ignores my request).

I can't get the patch to install, and I can't get the machine to shutdown. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to remove the power from the PC and restart. First, try to boot in. If it attempts to resume the update, then remove power again and this time boot into Safety Mode With Networking.